# I set UITableView.contentsize,but the contentsize doesn't change instantly

Tags: uitableview

I set `UITableView.contentsize`, but the `contentsize` doesn't change instantly
only I call the `reloadData` method next time, the `contentsize` of the view seems to be changed.

Which method should I call if I want the `UITableView`'s contentsize to be changed instantly?.
I tried the `setNeedsDisplay` method, but it doesn't work.

```
 _tableView .contentSize = CGSizeMake(
   _tableView.frame.size.width,rowHeight*(rowNumber+1)
 );
```

Comment: Are you calling that code from a background thread?